# Picking UVs from screen pixels in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics

I am trying to get the UV coordinates of a mesh at a given screen pixel. So, if a mesh is green on the screen at pixel (601,296), I want to know where on the texture I need to change to make the screen pixel at (601,296) red.

Using Camera.ScreenPointToRay() and then getting hit.textureCoord from that works great, but it is very slow. I need to do this for lots of pixels at once for a painting application.

I am currently rendering the scene with a shader that uses texcoord.xy as the fragment output, so that I can determine UV position just by looking at the pixel value. I render that to a RenderTexture and pick the colors from there. The problem is that the colors are snapping to increments of 0.004, so I can only color pixels on a grid and not continuously. Here is a [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wcirAvYKON41qSSgmkkjHem4FiARZk7g) of the problem.

Any idea how I can quickly pick UV positions from screen pixels with high precision?

Comment: The increments that you observe are caused by the 8-bit color resolution of your render target. Thus, if you want higher precision, you need to use more bits. Either use a different color format or use two channels for u and the other two channels for v. Btw, the texture coordinates alone are only half of the story. Once you have them, you also need to determine how you need to change the texture, such that the color at the given location is what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to give the render target more bits, even when increasing the depth of the RenderTexture. Using multiple channels definitely worked though! Thank you.